# how to avoid installing rails as a system gem by using bundler and expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, expect

I'm trying to make a new rails application with a intent not to install gems as system gem as possible.
At first I installed bundler as system gem, made a Gemfile which specified only rails and executed 'bundle install'. (In my opinion, bundler is OK to be a system gem...)

```
mkdir -p /opt/rails/rails_app
cd /opt/rails/rails_app
gem install bundler
bundle init
cp Gemfile /tmp
sed 's/#gem rails/gem rails/' /tmp/Gemfile > Gemfile
bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

Rails was installed as a 'local gem' which is limitted within /opt/rails/rails_app.

Then I tried to make a rails application by 'rails new'.

```
bundle exec rails new . --skip-bundle
```

This caused replacing the Gemfile, so a message was shown like this.

```
Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh]
```

Usually what should be done is only type 'y'. However, this time, I want to do that automatically for making a vagrant's provision script.

So I tried [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) but it never worked. All results were either timeout or syntax error:

```
expect -c "
spawn bundle exec rails new . --skip-bundle --quiet
expect \"Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter \"h\" for help) \[Ynaqdh\] \"
send \"y\r\"
"
```

I couldn't find where is wrong in this code and other solutions than using expect.

Comment: Have you looked at [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)?  They let you install Rubies and gems (including Rails) to your home directory.  No root privileges are needed.

Comment: No, I didn't. I'll try them.Thanks.

Comment: About the solution with expect, I got answer at another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601455/expect-script-string-with-square-braces-doesnt-match

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a `skip_gemfile` option in the rails [generator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3e36db4406beea32772b1db1e9a16cc1e8aea14c/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb#L197)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bundle install --path [directory]` to install you gems locally inside your app.  Typicall you would use './vendor/bundle' as your directory.