# expect script: string with square braces doesn't match

Tags: expect

I'm absolutely new to expect command.
Suppose that there is a script file named 'a.rb', which is written in ruby:

```
STDOUT << 'Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] '
s = STDIN.gets
STDOUT << s
```

It works as bellow:

```
$ruby a.rb
Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] #wait user's input
y  # show the user's input and exit
```

It seems good to use expect command if I want to automate the user's input.

So I tried to make a script file (a.expect):

```
spawn ruby a.rb
expect "Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile\? \(enter \"h\" for help\) \[Ynaqdh\] "
sleep 3
send "y\r"
```

But this script doesn't work and I don't know why.
That is my question.

```
$ expect -f a.expect
spawn ruby a.rb
Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] 
$  # <= expect script has finished because of (maybe) timeout?!
```

Comment: expect is a TCL extension. It has nothing to do with bash.

Comment: ...and on a different note, I would recommend against using `expect` for this use case -- it's overkill. Why not `yes y | ruby a.rb`?

Comment: ...however, if you *are* going to use `expect`, use `expect -d` to debug.

Comment: I didn't know yes command. great.

Comment: ...and that's only if the real `a.rb` doesn't have a way to run it in noninteractive mode where it doesn't need input on stdin in the first place. Most tools do -- and if they don't, you should consider submitting a patch upstream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These strings match, but **they don't glob to each other**. You need to use more escapes.

```
expect "Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile\? \(enter \"h\" for help\) \\\[Ynaqdh\\\] "
```

This is because `[abcd]` matches `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` -- one character -- not `[abcd]` (a six-character string).

Comment: I changed number of backslash(`expect "Overwrite /opt/rails/rails_app/Gemfile\? \(enter \"h\" for help\) \\\[Ynaqdh\\\] "`). however, it doesn't work as it is intended. but anyway yes command was really nice answer to me. it solved my problem immediately. I don't stick to using expect.

Comment: It certainly does send `y` back to the application. If you don't see the application echo the `y` back out, I suggest not exiting immediately at that point. You could, for instance, put an `expect y` at the end.